# Frustrated with PHP form - jquery mobile

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, post

Hi I am trying to resolve a problem - the problem is that I am getting the following message returned

Notice: Undefined index: username in J:\DynanicWeb_SM\EasyPHP-12.1\www\council\ratesform.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: password in J:\DynanicWeb_SM\EasyPHP-12.1\www\council\ratesform.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: rates in J:\DynanicWeb_SM\EasyPHP-12.1\www\council\ratesform.php on line 4
welcome twice again 
 when I submit a form as follows

```
    function sanitizeString($var){
        $var = htmlentities($var);
        $var = strip_tags($var);
        return $var;
    }

    function sanitizeMySQL($var) {
        $var =  mysql_real_escape_string($var);
        $var = sanitizeString($var);
        return $var;
    }

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
             if (!$con) {
                die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
                } else{

    mysql_select_db("council", $con); 

    $query = "SELECT `pid` FROM `payid` INNER JOIN `user` ON `user`.`uid` = `payid`.`uid` WHERE `user`.`username` = '". $username . "' AND `user`.`password` = '" . $pass ."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        if (isset($row))    {
                    echo "welcome  $row $username $pass  twice again";
        }
        if (!isset ($row)) {echo "failure again";
    }

    mysql_close($con);
    }
        ?>
```

from what I understand is that the $row is set - hence the  "welcome .."part but the remainder of the variables are not echoed out. I am using jQuery mobile 1.8.2  and was wondering if this is the problem or am I being a dumb@ss? 
This is a college project and do not have time just now to go down the mysqli route just now - I am just tring to get the project finished and will look at the PDO etc later. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Are you sure you want to echo out a password in cleartext? (besides actually storing it like that). Did you var_dumped $username and $password? And where is the array whose indexes error out? I can't see $rates too. Looks like you're omitting the relevant part

Comment: sorry first part was <?php 
  $username = sanitizeMySQL($_POST['username']);
  $pass = sanitizeMySQL($_POST['password']);
  $rates = sanitizeMySQL($_POST['rates']);

Comment: Ok, that means the $_POST array isn't populated...You should make sure it is before trying to access its indexes

Comment: I do not want to echo the result out but use it to insert into a seperate table - backtracking has shown that there is an error in the first stage so want to solve that before proceeding to insert on an inner join etc.

Comment: the POST part was replaced with get and I got the following  http://127.0.0.1/council/ratesform.php?username=drink&password=beer&rates=45 and the web page returned Notice: Array to string conversion in J:\DynanicWeb_SM\EasyPHP-12.1\www\council\ratesform.php on line 29
welcome Array drink beer twice again

Comment: just out of interest what do you think function sanitizeString($var){
        $var = htmlentities($var);
        $var = strip_tags($var);
        return $var;
    } this does?

Comment: http://kunststube.net/escapism/

Answer (score 0):

As this issue may be of some relevance to you here is how the thing works - as I said my issue as identified by others was mainly due to the fact that the _post info was not being transmitted through to the $_post variable  no fault in coding so I altered it to $_REQUEST and hey presto - works - simplze:-)

```
    <?php 
    $username = sanitizeMySQL($_REQUEST['username']);
    $pass = sanitizeMySQL($_REQUEST['password']);
    $rates = sanitizeMySQL($_REQUEST['rates']);

    function sanitizeString($var){
        $var = htmlentities($var);
        $var = strip_tags($var);
        return $var;
    }

    function sanitizeMySQL($var) {
        $var =  mysql_real_escape_string($var);
        $var = sanitizeString($var);
        return $var;
    }

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
             if (!$con) {
                die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
                } else{

    mysql_select_db("council", $con); 

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `payid` INNER JOIN `user` ON `user`.`uid` = `payid`.`uid` WHERE `user`.`username` = '". $username . "' AND `user`.`password` = '" . $pass ."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
    $pid =  $row['pid'];
    if (isset($result)) {
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `fees` (rates, pid) VALUES    ($rates,  $pid)");
    header ("Location: acc.html");

        }
        if (!isset ($result)) {echo "failure again";
    }

    mysql_close($con);
    }
        ?>
```